# Restrict adding of events for calendar portlet in Liferay

Tags: calendar, liferay, hook, portlet, liferay-6

Hi I need inputs on achieving the following scenario.
I have two user groups  "Teachers" and "Students" and I have one calendar portlet on my portal. I want to give access to only "Teachers" group to create new event/ and delete events in the calendar portlet and the students to only view the calendar.
Can anyone let me know how this particular scenario be implemented ?
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that calendar-portlet and calendar-entry is not the same. The calendar portlet is only "window" to all calendars that user has viewable access. However, the permission should be configured for calendars not for calendar-portlet. See the attachment:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 roles 1 for teachers and 1 for students and associate them to respective user group from Control Panel Group Management option.. So user in respective groups will get there appropriate roles. you can add respective permission of add / update / delete for teachers role from Control Panel > Roles > Define Permissions > Select Calendar portlet and select appropriate permission.. similarly for students to just give view right.

You can go through Roles & Permission assignment in Liferay administration guide. and how to associate role to user group..

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide

Comment: Hi Ankit, thanks for your reply. I am unable to find "Add EVENT  " Permissions under Control Panel > Roles > Define Permissions > Select Calendar portlet. Im using Liferay 6.2 instance. Can you please check and confirm. I am using Liferay's built in portlet

Comment: you need to get the calendar portlet from marketplace http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/managing-events-and-calendar-resources-with-liferay-rsquo-s-calendar

Comment: Im having the calendar portlet already. But in the Configuration, there is no option for "permissions for adding new events"

Comment: control panel administration for Role > Define Permission you do not see the Calendar Portlet ?

Comment: Ankit. Thanks for your time. I have updated the question by attaching the calendar permissions. Eventhough I am setting only VIEW permission, I am able to add and delete the event. I have created two rules Rule1 with All the permissions being set and Rule2 with only view permission. 

These rules are assigned to two users, user1 with Rule1 and user2 with Rule2. However, the user2 with Rule2(view onlY) is able to add a calendar event.

Comment: I faced similar problem... Have u find any solution for this?